# Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups using Divisibility Ordering of Integers

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I'm teaching an Advanced Algebra seminar and presented a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups that followed the proof presented by Herstein in Topics in Algebra. In that proof you look at relations among generators of the group G and use that to peel away cyclic groups as direct summands of G, which leave the infinite sums at the end.  In the proof you treat the finite and the infinite summands slightly differently.

A student in the class modified the proof by ordering the integers, not by their size, but by the divisibility relation $a\leq b$ iff $a\vert b$.  If we define $\mathbb{Z}_0= 
\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z} =\mathbb{Z}$, one can treat the integer summands in the same manner as the finite summands. The $\mathbb{Z}^r$ summands still show up at the end of the proof, but now correspond to $0$ being the "only element" left in the set of coefficients of the equations relating the generators.

My question is:

Is a proof along these lines known?

I haven't found it in my review of the proofs available online or in my algebra texts.  If this idea is already known, can someone publish a reference?  Thank you!

Comment: Looking at divisibility is *the* natural way to look at those things. The whole theorem boils down to [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) for integer matrices, which has the "invariant factors" arranged so that each divides the next one.

Comment: It's certainly the case that in the final result, you will get the divisibility of the orders of the finite summands.  My question was about the method of proof.  In the wikipedia link, their method of proof is induction based using columns with non-zero indices left.  As part of the proof, they move all the zero columns to the right in the end, and then work on the left non-zero columns to achieve the divisibility condition $n_1\vert n_2, \ldots$.  In this manner,  they treat the finite and the infinite summands differently.

Comment: I want to add, that the constructions in the Smith normal form wiki link are similar to those used in the Herstein proof.